# Configure spring to use xml version 1.1 for webservice

Tags: xml, web-services, spring, xml-1.1

Im trying to configure Spring to use xml version 1.1 for my webservice.

After the client has connected to the wsdl I need the submitted xml message to be encoded using xml version 1.1 and not 1.0 as i need to allow more characters to be submitted.

Does anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thank you.